# Manually Performing ECB & CBC

Tags: computer-networks, cryptography, security, xor

I am learning about block ciphers and while I understand the concept of Electronic Codeblock mode and cipher block chaining, I could not find any relevant practical examples online. Can someone provide a short example of a scenario where we convert plain text into cipher text using ecb and cbc (with initialization vector and keys).

Answer (score 1):

A common scenario is browsing this page e.g. [TLS Transport Layer Security](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#page-22) uses CBC for example AES among others to encrypt the content between Stack exchange servers and your browser.

CBC Pseudocode for Encryption

```
cbc key IV plainText nBlocks =

   cipher[0] = IV

   for i = 0 to nBlocks-1
     cipher[i+1] = (encrypt key plainText[i]) XOR cipher[i]

  cipher
```

CBC Pseudocode for Decryption

```
cbc' key cipher nBlocks = 

 for i = nBlocks-1 downto 1
     plainText[i-1] = (decrypt key cipher[i]) XOR cypher[i-1]

  plainText
```

A naive encrypt function is

```
  encrypt key data = data xor key
  decrypt key data = data xor key
```

you could use this functions in something like this:

```
let a = [1,2,3]
let iv = 81
let key = 365

let cipher = cbc key iv a 3
```

and if you do

```
cbc' cipher key 4
```

you should get back [1,2,3]

Comment: By example I mean a step by step manual example to  show how cbc or ecb is performed. It's a practice question sort of thing for exam

Comment: @x89 Pseudocode now added

Comment: Still looking for an example on how to use it

Comment: I can't figure out how to use encrypt key etc

Comment: @x89 encrypt key depends from your cypher.  AES for example is very complex to describe.  A naive encrypt function  is xor : encrypt key data = data xor key and decrypt key cipher = data xor key